# How do I filter (or sort) repeated cell value combinations?

Tags: google-sheets, filter

I sell seven different books (call them books A, B, C, D, E, F, and G). An order consists of a combination of these seven books at a time, resulting in multiple orders that are the same, but with many variations. For example, one order may be for just A, two for A and B, three for A, B, F, and G, and so on.

I have my data set out in Google Sheets so that books A to G are in columns (N to T, if that helps) and I mark them as "1" when the book is included in an order, and "blank" if not. I want to sort them so I can pack and ship all matching orders at the same time. For example:

```
A
A
A
AB
ACG
ABCD
ABCD
ABDEFG
ABDEFG
```

I have been using the filter function to do this for the past three years (it only shows up each combination at a time), but it is incredibly time-consuiming to set up all of the necessary filters required for all possible combinations of the seven books. Is there a way to do this more easily?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75062651/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with another table that shows your manually entered desired results. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the values A, B, C... are in the range `N1:T1`, use `byrow()` and `filter()`, like this:

```
=query( 
  byrow( 
    N2:T, 
    lambda( 
      row, 
      if( 
        sum(row), 
        join("", filter(N1:T1, row)), 
        iferror(1/0) 
      ) 
    ) 
  ), 
  "where Col1 is not null order by Col1", 0  
)
```

This gives you a sorted list of all combinations in the data, repeating each combination as many times as that combination exists in the data.

To sort the *sheet* using these values, choose **View > Freeze > 1 row** and put this formula in row `1` of a free column:

```
={ 
  "Sort key"; 
  byrow( 
    N2:T, 
    lambda( 
      row, 
      if( 
        sum(row), 
        join("", filter(N1:T1, row)), 
        iferror(1/0) 
      ) 
    ) 
  ) 
}
```

Then select the new column and choose **Data > Sort sheet > Sort sheet by column**.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach not that different, depending on the kind of information you may need is to have a total amount per combination:

```
=QUERY(BYROW(N2:T,LAMBDA(each,IFERROR(JOIN(" ",FILTER(N1:T1,each=1))))),"SELECT Col1,COUNT(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 order by Col1")
```

That would give you a list of the orders and the amount of each one:

[image]